# How to create dynamic properties

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, expandoobject

I am reading an xml which contains elements as follows:

```
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
```

By using [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), we can create a dynamic object and can create properties like

```
dynamic obj1 = new ExpandoObject();
obj1.id = 1;
obj1.name = "Shrikey";
```

where id and name are typecasted to int and string respectively.

But the thing which I am interested is whether I can create the "property name" also dynamically based on the content in name attribute of element.

Hope I made my question clear.

Any suggestions on how it can be done either using ExpandoObject or any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the `ExpandoObject` to an `IDictionary<string,object>` representing the mappings of property names to property values, and then manipulate those mappings:

```
IDictionary<string,object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Add("id", 1);
```